# ZF: Custom route, make all parts as param

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller-router

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

I have a Zend Router that handles adding stuff to the basket. Now i'm building a customiser module, so the user can add as many parts, in different colors, on specified sections of the product.

My basic url is like this

```
http://www.domain.com/shop/add/custom/size/type
```

My current router.ini is like this

```
resources.router.routes.shopAddCustom.route = shop/add/custom/:size/:type/*
resources.router.routes.shopAddCustom.defaults.module = shop
resources.router.routes.shopAddCustom.defaults.controller = order
resources.router.routes.shopAddCustom.defaults.action = add
resources.router.routes.shopAddCustom.defaults.product = builder
```

What i would really like to acommodate are urls like this.

```
http://www.domain.com/shop/add/custom/size/type/part3/blue/right/part2/part6/both/part7/red/part1/left/orange/
```

Basicly the everything behind size/type/ is a part, a color or a section (right, left, both)

How can i get a single array of all url-path-parts after size/type?

```
array(0 => 'part3', 1 => 'blue', 2 => 'right', 3 => 'part2', 4 => 'part6' [...] );
```

If i just use `$this-_request->getParams();` i get an array like this

```
array('part3' => 'blue', 'right' => 'part2', 'part6' => 'both' [...] );
```

I could run through that array, adding all keys and values as values in a new array. Problem is, if the number of url-path-parts is odd the last part will not be returned to the params, as it is seen as a empty variable, thus not added to the params array.

Any ideas is much apreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how i think i could do this - Any other solutions are still welcome!

```
$size = $this->_getParam('size');
$type = $this->_getParam('type');

$baseRouterUrl = $this->_helper->url->url(array('size' => $size, 'type' => $type), 'shopAddCustom', true);
$pathInfo = dirname($this->_request->getPathInfo() . '/.');

$pathInfo = str_replace($baseRouterUrl, '', '/' . $pathInfo);
$pathInfo = trim($pathInfo, '/\\');

$pathArr = explode('/', $pathInfo);
```

This is the resulting array.

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "part3"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "right"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "part2"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "part6"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "both"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "part7"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "red"
  [8]=>
  string(5) "part1"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "left"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "orange"
}
```

Comment: I'm using this now, at it's great :)